# form.is_valid() is false why?

Tags: python, django, sms, twilio

I want to store a POST request to a database, so I a had model form MessageForm and called it from views to validate the data and save it.

models.py

```
class phoneNumber(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address


class Message(models.Model):
    to = models.ForeignKey(phoneNumber, null=True)
    sentfrom = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.content)
```

forms.py

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        to = kwargs.pop('to', '')
        super(MessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['to']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=phoneNumber.objects.filter(address=to))
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def incoming(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            twiml = '<Response><Message>Yes</Message></Response>'
        else:
            twiml = '<Response><Message>No</Message></Response>'
    else:
        twiml = '<Response><Message></Message></Response>'
    return HttpResponse(twiml, content_type='text/xml')
```

Nothing is saved and I get `No` response when I test it.

Comment: What does it say in `form.errors` when it isn't valid?

Comment: <ul class="errorlist"><li>to<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul> <bound method MessageForm.non_field_errors of <MessageForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(to;sentfrom;content)>>

Answer (score 2):

You can access your errors in `views.py`

```
@csrf_exempt
def incoming(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            twiml = '<Response><Message>Yes</Message></Response>'
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            print(form.non_field_errors)
            twiml = '<Response><Message>No</Message></Response>'
    else:
        twiml = '<Response><Message></Message></Response>'
    return HttpResponse(twiml, content_type='text/xml')
```

Comment: How can I access and print these errors? I'm using request library to make a post request through the shell  ....   r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/incoming', data={'to':'0734567890', 'sentfrom':'12341234', 'content':'hello'})

Comment: If you are running ./manage.py runserver you can see in the django terminal these errors.

Comment: But you can change the response message to `<Response><Message>{{ form.errors }}</Message></Response>` I guess

Comment: The errors in terminal: <ul class="errorlist"><li>to<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
<bound method MessageForm.non_field_errors of <MessageForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(to;sentfrom;content)>>

Comment: Is it possible that the error in forms.py? I'm guessing the field `'to'` is not selecting a valid foreign key choice.

Comment: Yes, I guess the problem is this.

Comment: How can I fixed it? The form as it is now is pretty much all I can do.

Comment: It didn't work without `self.fields['to']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=phoneNumber.objects.filter(address=to))`  ?

Comment: I deleted it and it still didn't work. I get the same error.

Comment: I think I have it, remove the kwargs.pop() too. If it doesn't work, sorry I cannot help you more :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    to = kwargs.pop('to', '')
    super(MessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['to'].queryset = phoneNumber.objects.filter(address=to)
```

Also I'm not sure if you want to pass anything to the form in views method, because right now your `to` in form is empty string, so your queryset is querying on `phoneNumber.objects.filter(address='')`, which may or may not be what you want.

**Edit**:

The reason that `to` is empty string because `kwargs.pop('to', '')` means "pop argument `to` out from kwargs, if `to` is not there the default is `''`". In your views you do:

```
form = MessageForm(request.POST)
```

but you didn't feed the constructor with any `to` argument, so `kwargs.pop('to', '')` would get `''` as default value. You might need something like:

```
form = MessageForm(request.POST, to="white house")
```

Comment: `to` being an empty string might be the problem but why is it an empty string? the `address` already populated with numbers and the POST request is meant to match `to` with one of those numbers.

Comment: I edited my answer on why your `to` might be empty string in your form. But then I start to question the reason you pass `to` to you form. Why do you do that?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't realize I was passing an empty string. I wanted to make OneToMany relationship, so all of the text messages sent are matched and displayed with the numbers from phoneNumber model. The idea is that I get the post request from Twilio and catch the `To` field and match it with the ones in my database and save the messages under this number. Can you help me fix `to` to achieve this?

Comment: The `queryset` for `ModelChoiceField` are available choices, not the actual data you will assign to it, so I guess you could remove the `__init__` method all together. Can you try that?